# Loop to compare dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to write a loop whereby for example if a "order date" is equal to "delivery date" it would give me a categorical value (1 or 0) in a new column.

Below is the code I tried:

```
pl['same_jb_sr'] = 0

for dates in pl.iterrows():
    if pl['SampleReceivedDate'] != pl['JobCreationDate']:
        pl.loc['same_jb_sr'] = 1 
    else:
        pl.loc['same_jb_sr'] = 0
```

SampleReceivedDate and JobCreationDate are of data type "Datetime64 [ns]".

The error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: What data structure is `pl`? A dictionary, a dateframe or something else? What is the error message? Can you include the content of `pl` in your question?

Comment: Hi, pl is the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written the loop. For example see below:

```
for pl in data:
    pl['same_jb_sr'] = int(pl['SampleReceivedDate'] != pl['JobCreationDate'])
```

I used `int` here as the operation returns a `bool` and using `int` on it turns it to `1` if `True` and `0` if `False`, so no need for the if/else statement.

Comment: Hi Jab, I used your code and this was the error message  I got:  "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>". The data type for 'sampleReceivedDate' and 'Job CreateionDate' is datetime64 [ns].